# mySQL index parameters and limits

Tags: mysql, database, select, indexing

I am trying to figure out the settings in mySQL on indexes.  When does mySQL ignore an index?

Here are the results of an experiment.  I have a table with an index on the AGE column as follows.

```
CREATE TABLE `USERS` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `FIRSTNAME` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `LASTNAME` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `USERNAME` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ROLE` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PASSWORD` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AGE` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `USERS`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  ADD KEY `AGE` (`AGE`);
```

Results of EXPLAIN queries.  The first three statements use the index.  The second set of statements ignore the index and do a full table scan.

The range of AGE is random between 20 and 100 years.  There are 1000 rows in the table.

```
/* utilizes the index on AGE */
/* case 1 */
SELECT ID, AGE  FROM USERS WHERE AGE > 20; 

/* case 2 */
SELECT AGE  FROM USERS WHERE AGE > 44;

/* case 3 */
SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE AGE > 84;


/* does not use index on AGE */

/* case 4 */
SELECT AGE, FIRSTNAME FROM USERS WHERE AGE > 83;

/* case 5 */
SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE AGE > 83;

/* case 6 */
SELECT AGE FROM USERS WHERE AGE > 18;
```

Some observations that I have seen. Can anyone confirm my conclusions are correct?

1) SELECT * will use the index when 15% or fewer of the rows are selected.
2) SELECT AGE will use the index when 1 or more rows are selected.

Comment: Use formatting tools to make your post more readable. Use `code blocking` for code and log and error texts and **bold** and *italics* to highlight things

Comment: I presume these are all tested against the same table.  Case 3 and case 5 are particularly puzzling.  Possibly retest with caching disabled (i.e. `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE <rest of query>).

Answer (score 3):

The 15% is usually around 20%, and it depends on statistics gleaned from data in the table.  I saw someone nail down about 29% as the cutoff in his query.  You are actually hitting 20%:

```
(100-85+1)/(100-20+1) = 19.8%
(100-84+1)/(100-20+1) = 21.0%
```

So, that explains cases 3, 4, 5.  The rationale is that for a high percentage, a table scan is more efficient than bouncing between the index BTree and the data+PK BTree.

The index is "covering" for these two.  That is, *all* the necessary columns are found in a single index.  Hence, it *should* use the index, not do a table scan:

```
SELECT AGE ...
SELECT ID, AGE ...
```

Note:  In InnoDB, secondary indexes include the `PRIMARY KEY` implicitly.  That is, `INDEX(age)` is virtually the same as `INDEX(age, id)`.

That explains case 1 and 2, but fails to explain case 6.  Case 6 should have used the index to return the entire list of AGEs.  (not 0 rows, as your comment states??)

Your tests are the tip of the iceberg, but you have gotten a lot farther than most beginners at trying to fathom the depths of MySQL's relatively simple Optimizer.  (I have several years' head start on you.)

There are a few more Rules of Thumb [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) .

Please continue experimenting and publishing your results.

Comment: Great response, but not clear to me how 3 (used index) and 5 (didn't) are explained by your first statement.  Could you elaborate?

Comment: @JoshuaR. - Case 3 had fewer index rows to touch, so the back and forth was deemed not-too-costly.  Case 5 had more.